# Getting an illegal start of type error

Tags: java

I am getting an "illegal start of type" error with this block:

```
if (maritalStatus.equals("Single") || maritalStatus.equals("single")){
        taxableIncome = grossIncome - deductions - (dependents * allowance);
} else if (maritalStatus.equals("Married") || maritalStatus.equals("married")){
        taxableIncome = grossIncome - deductions - ((dependents + 2) * allowance);
}
```

Also, how do I use the below statement when it comes to single/Single and married/Married?

```
Boolean equalsIgnoreCase (String thisString)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why you are getting an error with your code, but you would use equalsIgnoreCase like this:

```
if (maritalStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("Single")) {
    taxableIncome = grossIncome - deductions - dependents * allowance;
} else if (maritalStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("Married")) {
    taxableIncome = grossIncome - deductions - (dependents + 2) * allowance;
}
```

I also took out your extraneous parentheses.